# Union All With if/else T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I was wondering how I can have a UNION ALL with IF/ELSE statement.

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM A
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM B
UNION ALL

IF @type = 1
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM C
   END
ELSE
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM D
   END

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM E
```

I get syntax error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM A 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM B 
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM C WHERE @type = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM D WHERE @type <> 1 OR @type IS NULL
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM E ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Well one way to do it is use dynamic sql

first build the query string and then execute it. That way you have full control

```
declare query nvarchar(max)
set query = 'SELECT * FROM A
             UNION ALL
             SELECT * FROM B
             UNION ALL '

IF @type = 1
BEGIN
set query = query + '
            SELECT * FROM C'
END
ELSE
BEGIN
set query = query + '
            SELECT * FROM D'
END
set query = 'UNION ALL
             SELECT * FROM E'

exec(query)
```

Comment: okay now that is uncalled for - I mentioned that this is one way of doing it, and it works fine. Dynamic sql is bad only when you let sql injection attacks by concatenating parameters without sanitizing them.

Comment: @Roopesh Shenoy: Let's say this is in a stored proc. The caller can execute the stored proc but not query tables directly (ownership chaining). Using EXEC like this will fail: permissions need granted on the tables now. Running the stored proc with EXECUTE AS OWNER is an unnecessary escalation. It's not all SQL injection issues but simple security... or do you run everything as sa or db_owner?

Comment: @gbn - that is probably a good concern for a dba when the final deployment scenario and security model is not considered properly by the developer. However it is a standard language feature and is available in almost all the databases I have worked with.

Comment: @Roopesh Shenoy: Standard or not, in this case dynamic SQL compromises the system. Security is never an afterthought

Comment: - 1 to gbn: stored procedures are a fact of life. I think the other answer is more elegant, but that does not mean this answer is insecure.